# What fraction of smarties are brown?

Tags: fractions

If I have 26 smarties and 2 of them are brown, what fraction is that?

Answer (score 3):

The fraction of smarties that are brown is $\frac{2}{26}=\frac{2\times 1}{2\times 13}=\frac{1}{13}$.

Comment: Adding on a little: In general, if you have "$some$ out of $total$ are brown," the fraction equivalent is: $$\frac{some}{total}$$